# Meaning of "crawdaddy"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Today’s incident is just the kind of unfortunate mishap that can
> happen when you kowtow to the latest fashions from overseas. We’re
> going to get to the bottom of this, gentlemen, I can give you my blood
> oath on that little **crawdaddy**.

This excerpt is from *The Intuitionist* by Colson Whitehead. (Page 27, which can be [previewed in-context](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Intuitionist/WJEA1TTHu8AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=crawdaddy&pg=PA27&printsec=frontcover) on Google Books). This is what the elevator inspector's guild chair said at a press conference after the newly installed elevator had fallen.
I wonder what would crawdaddy refers to in this kind of situation.

Comment: A "crawdad" is a term for [crayfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crayfish). The speaker seems to be using it to refer to whatever the antecedent of "this" is—"today's incident"? You might get better results if you can provide a bit more context.

Comment: Yep, when I was a 10-year-old in rural Louisville, Ky,  every kid knew what a "crawdad"/"crawdaddy" was.  Though you would get strange looks if you called it a "crayfish".

Comment: @AndyBonner The quote in its full, original context can be seen on Google Books [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Intuitionist/WJEA1TTHu8AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=crawdaddy&pg=PA27&printsec=frontcover). Just submitted an edit to include that link in the question as well.

Comment: Link doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

In short, there is no literal meaning of 'crawdaddy' involved here. It is simply an informal and figurative use of the word.

To explain, there is no interpretation of that context where an elevator accident might be labeled a small freshwater lobster-like crustacean and it is unlikely for it to be a mistake, some slip of the mind or symptom of a stroke.

What is most likely is that the speaker (as written by the author) is using a common trope of, instead of being formal and saying:

> ... we're going to 1) discover the reasons for this 2) accident.

he says

> ... we're going to 1) get to the bottom of this 2) crawdaddy.

where 'crawdaddy' is intended to mean 'situation', 'incident'. 'thing'.

I've never heard 'crawdaddy' used this way, but it is not wrong (though it is a very surprising choice by the author). 'Crawdaddy' (and variations like 'crawdad' or 'crawfish') is very much a Southern version of 'crayfish' so it gives local color. Having grown up in a location where people use the term 'crawdad', the more diminutive 'crawdaddy' sounds a little too cutesy to me.

A more likely choice of word that I've heard serving the same function is 'baby' or, even more colorful, 'puppy' as in:

> ... we're going to 1) get to the bottom of this 2) puppy.

It's all intended, instead of the bland ineffable 'thing', to make it less bland, while still being ineffable.

Though none of 'baby', 'puppy', or the outlandish 'crawdaddy' actually denote 'incident', they're just used to stand in without actually saying the word 'incident' or 'accident'.

Comment: Given the incident is an unfortunate one, I interpret *that little crawdaddy* someone's personal stand-in for m-w's meaning 3 of [*bugger*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bugger): "A small or annoying thing. *put down the keys and now I can't find the bugger*" In other words, trying to minimize the incident as something that can easily be taken care of.

Comment: @DjinTonic Yes, 'bugger' is another stand-in that has no literal meaning here (sounds british to me - not used in US).